# Ascii console game: player character

Tags: c#, console-application, ascii

I've been working on a game for a while now. It's an ASCII game in the console, using C#. It's a bit like the old top-down zelda games. I've managed to get the map to draw, the movement system works and I've added random encounters.

Since I am still a beginner, I don't know how to use classes yet, so the game is programmed entirely without them.

My player character currently is still just the cursor, but I would like it to be a bit easier to see. It could be a white "@" symbol or something. The map is in color, so after the @ symbol moves, the right tile, with the right color should be placed back at where the character was. I've tried quite some times, but I simply haven't been able to figure out how I can get this to work.

So my question is: How do I draw a white "@" character where the cursor is on the map and how do I make sure it doesn't leave the map changed when the "@" symbol moves as the player moves?

If you need any more information, simply tell me and I'll post it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) You set the position and then write a single @ character. 2) You do the same for the part of the map that @ was on, but rewrite the map tile.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is a good combination of Console.SetCursorPosition and Console.Clear. Try experimenting with that.